# Difficulty Registering Defaults for iOS App

Tags: swift, settings.bundle

I've been working on a settings bundle for my iOS app and have added a few toggle switches to set units. For some reason the way I've been registering the defaults on launch isn't working. In my appDelegate's didFinishLaunching method I've added:

```
let defaultDict  = ["altitudeMeters" : 3.28084]

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defaultDict)

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

When I launch the app and fetch the value for the toggle switch with id 'altitudeMeters' it returns '0.0'. If I change the position of the switch it then returns the values entered in my settings bundle. Am I missing something while registering my default value for this switch?

The switch is set up as follows:

[image]

I have been attempting to access the value using:

```
let altitudeFactor = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("altitudeMeters")
```

After setting up the default elsewhere, originally using the code posted earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you store your dictionary it stores it as [NSObject : AnyObject]?, so you will need to do it as follow:

let myDefaultDict  = ["altitudeMeters" : 3.28084]

```
func saveMyDictionary(){
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myDefaultDict, forKey: "myDefaultDict")
}
func loadAltitude() -> Double? {
    if let loadedDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("myDefaultDict") {
        if let altitudeStored = loadedDictionary["altitudeMeters"] as? Double {
            return altitudeStored
        }
    }
    return nil
}

saveMyDictionary()

let altitudeFactor = loadAltitude() // it will return an optional

println(altitudeFactor!)  // you can force unwrap it if you are sure it wont be nil

// otherwise you can you if let
if let altitudeFactor = altitudeFactor {
    println(altitudeFactor) // inside the brackets it is not an optional
}
```

if you need to remove/reset its value :

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("myDefaultDict")
```

you can save it also as Double instead of a Dictionary like this:

```
func saveAltitudeMeters(high:Double){
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(high, forKey: "altitudeMeters")
}
func loadAltitudeMeters() -> Double? {
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("altitudeMeters")
}

saveAltitudeMeters(3.7)

if let loadedAltitudeMeters = loadAltitudeMeters() {
    println(loadedAltitudeMeters)   // 3.7
}
```

Comment: I tried to add what you suggested but after launching the app, if I call the value of that setting using `let altitudeFactor = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("altitudeMeters")` I still get `0.0`

Comment: You are not doing what I told you to do

Comment: The way I understand it, the code you provided is still the code for AppDelegate that initializes the defaults. So how do I access the value for my switch in my view controller after setting them this way?

Comment: Do you think you could point me in the right direction in order to access my setting then? I'm a little confused.

Comment: I'm sorry to have to ask another stupid question, but right now I've got your functions set up in my AppDelegate and I ultimately need to access this value in my own View Controller. I don't think I can really create an instance of AppDelegate to call the loadAltitude() method. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: So I would put it in some arbitrary class, call the saveMyDictionary method in my viewDidLoad of my view controller and then if I call the loadAltitude method that will give me the value of my switch?

Comment: Well after trying those most recent functions straight in my view controller (they made the most sense to me) I got it! Thank you SO much for taking the time to work things through with me :) have a fantastic weekend!